# Json Syntax Exception: java .io .EOF Exception

Tags: android, json

May I know why does such an error occur?

> com. google. gson. JsonSyntaxException: java. io. EOFException: End of
>   input at line 3782 column 1

```
private void initView() {

    String js = loadJSONFromAsset(getActivity(), "brandtypes.json");
    Gson g = new Gson();
    BrandccokersHub p = g.fromJson(js, Brandcookers.class);
    List<BrandCountryList> ctry = p.getCountryList();
    List<BrandTypeBrandList> ctrycook = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ctry.size(); i++) {
        ctrycook.clear();
        if (ctry.get(i).getBrandId() == mPosition) {
            ctry.get(i).getBrandType();
            ctryCook.addAll(ctry.get(i).getBrandList());

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your json isn't valid, and is missing some terminators most likely.  Run it through jsonlint.

Comment: Here I have done a small mistake, the  position values I have given here was wrong because of that I was getting error. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 private void initView() {

    String js = loadJSONFromAsset(getActivity(), "brandtypes.json");
    Gson g = new Gson();
    Brandcookers p = g.fromJson(js, Brandcookers.class);
    List<BrandCountryList> ctry = p.getCountryList();
    List<BrandTypeBrandList> ctrycook = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ctry.size(); i++) {
        ctrycook.clear();
        if (ctry.get(i).getBrandId() == mPosition) {
            ctry.get(i).getBrandType();
            ctryCook.addAll(ctry.get(i).getBrandList());

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aren't both same?

Comment: you cannot cast Brandcookers to BrandccokersHub in line num 3